# Getting errors when including sdl2/sdl_image.h

Tags: c, sdl-2

So my problem with SDL2 is the moment i include SDL2/SDL_image.h like this :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

Even without using any function of sdl_image, when i compile i get a lot of errors.

I get 3 types of errors:

> conflicting types (exp: error conflicting types for
> 'SDL_ThreadPriority').

and redeclaration of enumerator (exp: error redeclaration of enumerator SDL_ASSERTION_ABORT).

And : redefinition of (exp: error redefinition of 'struct SDL_RWops').

I am on Linux and i am using the c language, i have tried compiling with gcc and mingw in codeblocks, i get the same errors.

I have SDL2_image installed and I linked it in the compilers.

Comment: What else do you include? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please give more details like: compiler messages, your code, you environment

Comment: i include stdio.h stdlib.h , SDL2/SDL.h, and SDL2/SDL_image.h

Comment: as for the environement its codeblocks and mingw.

Comment: i couldn't write the code here (i'm struggling with stackoverfolw) but its just the code for opening a window and drawing a rectangle.

Comment: the problem is when i include SDL2/SDL_image.h

Comment: You have a configuration issue with Code::Blocks it appears. The SDL2 headers all contain proper header-guards that prevent multiple inclusion. But the fact you get a redeclaration of `SDL_ThreadPriority` is strange since that is only declared in the header `SDL_thread.h` which is include by `SDL.h`. So there should be no conflict with anything in `SDL_Image.h`.

Answer (score 1):

OK guys i resolved my problem.

what caused the conflict was sdl2 being installed twice the first through package manager, and the second manually by compiling from source.

so i had two SDL2 directories one in: /usr/include  and the second in: /usr/local/include.

when installed libsdl2-image-dev automatically through package manager, it was installed, in: /usr/include and not the later and thats what caused problems when i started using in in my programs.
So all i had to do is uninstall the one in /usr/local/include and thats it.